# Phonegap asking for too many permissions

Tags: android, permissions, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

When I'm building my app into a .APK file and while trying to install it on my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone it's asking for all the permissions like Camera.

The app supposed to be not asking any permissions except for INTERNET because it needs it.

I checked my config.xml file but it should be fine.

**I'm using the Phonegap Build version.**

Android target: 4+

more Phonegap info: http://prntscr.com/aiqv7q

config.xml: (obviously left out the author name etc.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.phonegap.helloworld"
    version   = "1.0.0">

<!-- Define the main entry-point to the application -->
<content src="index.html" />

<!--
    If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
    following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
    permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
-->
<preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

<!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
<preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
<preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
<preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
<preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
<preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
<preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
<preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
<preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
<preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="14" />              <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
<preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
<!--
    Define a specific version of PhoneGap to build into your app.
    <preference name="phonegap-version"       value="3.5.0" />
-->

<!-- Plugins -->

<!-- Core plugins -->
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />

<!-- Third party plugins -->
<!-- A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/plugins -->
<!--
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
-->

<!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

<!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png"      gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"              gap:platform="blackberry" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"           gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg"      gap:platform="winphone" />

<!--
    Define access to external domains.

    <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
    <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.

    Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
-->
<access origin="*"/>
<!--
   <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
   <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
   <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
```

-->

Comment: Since this is your first post about *Phonegap Build*
Is this your first App? What is your target platform and their target versions? Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume - please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650  I just edited after a long time. Still got the same issue.

Comment: Okay. Let me look at it. It will be a while. IS THIS YOUR FIRST APP? I forgot to ask, Are you using *Phonegap Desktop App*?

Comment: NEVER MIND. You are using *Phonegap Desktop App*. This is your first app. ---- This is a common problem. I am going to blog on this tonight. I will post an answer later tonight.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650, I wish your day end soon. I too am looking for answer.